# DietPi does not detect Wifi. Raspbian does detect WiFI

Tags: raspbian, wifi, dietpi

I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B with two 32GB SD cards.  I installed Raspbian on the first card and I have played with it for a few weeks.

Yesterday I installed Diet Pi on the other SD card and booted up the PI.  I am able to login, however I am not able to setup WiFi.  I go through this process:

1. Login as root
2. Type: dietpi-config at the command prompt
3. Select option 7: Network Options Adapter
4. Select wifi
5. Select scan (scan and configure SD)
6. Select slot 0 (Unused: Select to configure)
7. Select Scan: Scan and Configure and SSID

After option 7 is selected, then I am returned to option 6.  Why?

My Pi is located next to my router.  I even tried positioning it on the next desk along and the next one after that.

Comment: Have you configured the country you are in? Some WiFi channels are not allowed in every country world wide and thus they will be ignored if you are in the wrong country.

Comment: @Robert, is that specific for Diet Pi? Raspbien worked "out of the box".  Thanks.

Comment: Note that DietPi has it's own forum: https://dietpi.com/phpbb/index.php